# Aggregate string values to array of unique string values per field with mongo or mongoose and node.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I need to aggregate "lastNames" and "occupations" for a "name" to get a result:

```
{
  name: 'John',
  occupations: ['software engineer', 'qa']
  lastNames: ['Smith', 'Red', 'Doe']
}
```

input

```
name: 'John'
```

documents present in mongo:

```
{name: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', occupation: 'software engineer'}
{name: 'Steve', lastName: 'Smith', occupation: 'senior software engineer'}
{name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', occupation: 'qa'}
{name: 'Steve', lastName: 'Doe', occupation: 'manager'}
{name: 'John', lastName: 'Red', occupation: 'software engineer'}
```

I started with this aggregation query:

```
Employees.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: name } },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$lastName',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$occupation',
    },
  },
  { $group: { _id: '$name' } },
]);
```

but this returns an empty array, so I kinda stuck as I never did aggregations before.

Is there a way to produce this required result?

Comment: Your documents do not contain any array, thus `$unwind` is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { name: "John" } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$name",
         occupations: { $addToSet: "$occupation" },
         lastNames: { $addToSet: "$lastName" },
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         _id: 0,
         name: "$_id",
         occupations: 1,
         lastNames: 2
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZuaEKtnX2du)

Comment: so occupations & lastNames will hold only unique values?

Comment: just read docs: The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.


great thanks!